# Search value in column in CSV file using Python

Tags: python

I need to scan through line by line in time column time in CSV file, and see if there was activity in another column during 5 hours ago, then add column with value 1.

Here is my idea:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple
from contextlib import closing
light3 = pd.read_csv('G:/light3.csv')
light3.Time = pd.to_datetime(light3.Time)

m = light3.Time - DateOffset(hours = 5)
def search():
    item = light3[(light3['Time']> m)| (light3['Time']== m)]
    raw_data = 'G:/light3.csv'

    failure = 'No matching item could be found with that item code. Please try again.'
    check = False
with open('G:/project/test.pcap_z/light.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('G:/light1.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

        read_data = csv.DictReader(csvinput, delimiter=';')
        item_data = namedtuple(read_data['Time'], read_data.Time)
        all = [ ]
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('f')
        all.append(row)
        while check == False:
                for row in reader:
                    if row.Item == item:
                        row.append('f')
                        all.append(row)
                        row.append(1)

        writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? And, if you want us to debug it, the code seems nice and short and complete, but it's still not a [mcve] without sample input and desired output.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.